# Is it possible to use values in an array for implicit aggregate initialization/assignment of a struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

I have a struct

```
struct RGB {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
}
```

I know that aggregate initialization can be used:

```
RGB rgb = {255, 255, 255};
```

I wonder if it is possible to assign an array to it. I've tried these solutions and they do not work:

```
int rgb_array[] = {255, 255, 255};
rgb = rgb_array; //error
std::array<int, 3U> rgb_array2 = {255, 255, 255};
rgb = rgb_array2; //error
```

Is there a way to do this at all?

I'm open to corrections or clarifications in my question if need be. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to keep RGB an aggregate?

Comment: First of all, `rgb = ...` is not initialization, it's *assignment*. Initialization happens when you define variables (like in `RGB rgb = ...`). Secondly no it's not possible without defining suitable operators or constructors.

Comment: @NathanOliver no, it can become anything as long as it's not more than two steps long.

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can do it like this, operator overloading inside the struct RGB, as long as you know that the order of the array is r,g,b

```
#include <iostream>

struct RGB {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

    RGB() = default;
    RGB(const int (&arr)[3]) {
        this->r = arr[0];
        this->g = arr[1];
        this->b = arr[2];
    }
};

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
    //with initialization
    //RGB rgb = arr;

    //with assignment
    //RGB rgb;
    //rgb = arr;

    std::cout << rgb.r << ',' << rgb.g << ',' << rgb.b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be safe I would recommend using array references instead, like `RGB& operator=(const int (&arr)[3])` Then it can't be called with an array that is too small (or to large, though that's less of a problem).

Comment: And also replace `operator=` with a constructor. Then `=` will still work, and so will initialization with an array.